# How to switch to xslt 2.0 from xslt 1.0

Tags: xml, xslt, msxsl

I am using MSXSL.exe utility to trigger my xslt code to transform the source XML file to destination xml file. I am not able to use a lot of built in functions which are available in XSLT 2.0.

Although I have changed the header, XSLT version 2.0, still i am not able to use the XSLT 2.0 functions. Is this because MSXSL.exe doesnt support XSLT 2.0?

Please let me know some suggestions so that i can use format date, string concatenation functions in my code

Answer (score 2):

> Although I have changed the header, XSLT version 2.0, still i am not
>   able to use the XSLT 2.0 functions. Is this because MSXSL.exe doesnt
>   support XSLT 2.0?

Yes.

> Please let me know some suggestions so that i can use format date,
>   string concatenation functions in my code

Please ask a specific question about each problem you encounter. There is no generic recipe to replace XSLT 2.0 functionality in XSLT 1.0. For example, to "format a date", you need to provide us with the source and target formats, and the solution will probably be specific to those two.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use an XSLT 2.0 processor, on Windows which you seem to use if you mention msxsl you have some choice, the .NET version of Saxon 9 (which should work from the command line on Windows as the .NET framework is part of the OS in all supported Windows versions) or the Java version of Saxon 9 you could run if you install the Oracle Java JRE. There is also XmlPrime, a commercial implementation of XSLT 2.0, a pure .NET implementation.